# Javascript/Jquery not working in Spree

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, spree

Hey guys I have an application using spree and I need to implement some new javascript to create a new promotion rule. Unfortunately I'm unable to access any js files regardless of where I put them. I've even tried overriding sprees files such as promotions.js to implement new functions but it's just not going through. I've tried placing the js file in the following :

app/assets/javascript/spree/backend

vendor/assets/javascript/spree/backend

In my partial _product_value.html.erb :

```
<button class='cool'>okay</button>
```

In promotions.js

```
$('.cool').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    alert('donezo');
});
```

Comment: what is the error you are seeing in console?

Comment: No error, I'm just looking for the alert('donezo') to be displayed when I click the button, but nothing's happening.

Comment: please confirm if all your js files are loading. If your are using chrome then F12(will open developers tool) ->network tab (Reload application) -> You will see if files are successfully loading .Using filter icon to search by file name

Comment: @user2181397 It's being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Alright! I figured it out. I wrapped it around a document ready like so...

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $('.cool').on('click', function() {
       alert('donezo');
    });

    $("#ight").click(function() {
       alert('worked');
    });
 });
```

Threw promotions.js into app/assets/javascripts/backend and created a new all.js file in the same directory. I then added..

```
 //= require spree/backend/promotions.js
```

Below //= require_tree .